# PHP Automatic Function Arguments and Variables

Tags: php

I'm trying to do something similar to the segment structure in the Codeigniter system.

I want to transfer the parameters I get via REQUEST_URI to a function and call them with a variable name I want inside the function.

Example: /news/stock

```php
$arguments = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

// I want to pass this array to a function called route.

//But I want to call it like this.

call_user_func('route', $arguments); 

// Here the arguments go as arrays but below is what I want.

function route($page,$slug)
{
  //...
}
```

Parameters can be more than one. I want to specify the names in the function arguments in the function itself, in order of parameters.

Would you help me with this topic ?

Comment: You could use an array, since `a['catbus'] = 'ghibli'` is legal in PHP

Comment: @DaveS Using arrays will create code clutter. I've seen this done with unlimited variables. But I can't do it because I have little knowledge.

Comment: You can use the spread operator `...`, eg: call the function like `route(...$arguments)`. https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list

Comment: @Sammitch The example you gave doesn't quite meet what I want. I want to specify the variable names while specifying the function. Also I don't know how to pass it to the function

Comment: If you literally want variables named `$page` and `$slug` then use `list($page, $slug) = $arguments;`, but there's not really any functional difference between argument unpacking with `...` or having `list()` stuffed in between.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're looking for spread operator.
Or in PHP known as arguments unpacking.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php

Try this:

```
route(...$arguments);
```

I update your code to understand better.

```
$arguments = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

route(...$arguments); 

// Here the arguments going as you want!!!

function route($page,$slug)
{
  echo $page;// news
  echo $slig;//stock
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how I can use this with request_uri? Actually, there is a class I made. In it, I break the request_uri value as in the example above. I want to send these parameters to another class's method with call_user_func and use them in that method as in the example.

Comment: I detailed the question. Can you help me?

Comment: Its your arguments in line one passed to route function. It just not sending an array. It send array values as function arguments...

Comment: My answer is correct test it

Comment: Edited the answer for you if it worked for you please accept answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$arguments = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
function route ($arguments) {
if (isset($arguments[1]) && $arguments[1] == 'news' && isset($arguments[2])) {
 $page = isset($arguments[1]);
 $slug = isset($arguments[2]);
 echo $page . ' - ' . $slug;
}
```

Comment: I detailed the question. Can you help me? I am using call_user_func this answer is not enough.

Comment: Check here: https://zyrex.eu/funkcja-call_user_func/

Comment: function route() {
    $arguments = func_get_args();
    foreach ($arguments as $arg) {
        echo $arg . ' ';
    }
}